# Is this nested while-loop program correct and as clean as it can be? Please explain

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

Here is the 'finger exercise' I was given:

"Write a program that asks the user to enter an integer and prints two integers, root and pwr, such that 0 < pwr < 6 and root**pwr is equal to the integer entered by the user. If no such pair of integers exists, it should print a message to that effect."

I am only supposed to use while() and if(), as I haven't been exposed to anything else yet.
Below is the program I came up with after a ton of trial and error:

```
x = int(raw_input('Enter a positive integer: '))
pwr = 1
root = 1
while pwr < 6:
    if root**pwr == x:
        break
    root = root + 1
    while root**pwr < x:
        pwr = pwr + 1
if root**pwr == x:
    print 'Root =',str(root),'and pwr =',str(pwr)
else:
    print 'No pair of integers root and pwr exists such that root**pwr =',x, where 0 < pwr < 6
```

Please help me with the following questions I have:

1) Am I missing something that would make this program produce a false answer?

2) Is there a way to reorganize/rewrite the program so that it is leaner and more efficient? (ideally while sticking with the same general approach I've taken)

3) Can you please explain how the nested while loop stops and leads to the outer while loop running again? (Which I assume it does because it produces the correct integers for x=9 and x=16). It seems to me like the inner loop should eventually be false (pwr is increased to the point where root**pwr > x), causing the outer while loop to be false (because pwr is likely > 6, which would lead to the 'No pair...' print out at the end of my program. My course is supposed to have me learn by reading through python libraries and figuring it out myself, but all I've managed to do is write a program I don't fully understand.

Comment: Note: the last line of your code contains a syntax error `where 0 < pwr < 6`

Comment: A false answer not per se, but your code goes into an infinite loop.  Try entering "27" for example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Can you suggest how to fix the infinite loop? I'm not sure why it's happening.

Comment: As a couple of hints-- your outer loop is going while `pwr < 6`, so you would be best incrementing `pwr` in that loop, but not in the inner loop.  Instead increment `root` in the inner loop (not in the outer loop as you currently do).  The other hint would be that depending on how your loops are nested you may need to reset either `root` or `pwr` to 1 at the beginning of the outer loop each time it runs.

Comment: One more hint regarding the infinite loop-- as it is you'll never break out of the outer loop if `root**pwr < x` is already true, but `pwr < 6`.  In this case `pwr` will never be incremented enough times for the outer loop to be broken out of.

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific problems only, not general feedback. You'll be better served on a site like [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

def root_pwr(n):
    for pwr in range(1, 5):
        root = 1
        while root**pwr < n:
            root += 1
        if root**pwr == n:
            return 'Root = {} and pwr = {}'.format(root, pwr)
    return 'No pair of integers root and pwr exists such that root**pwr = ' + str(n) + ' where 0 < pwr < 6'

def main():
    i = ''
    while not i.isdigit():
        i = raw_input('Input an integer: ')

    print root_pwr(int(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Maybe I'm missing something in the problem, but based on my understanding, the solution will always be pwr = 1 and root = int(input()) (i in my program, x in yours).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the hints, suggestions, and for pointing me to Code Review. Code Review is exactly what I'm looking for. As for this question, I've managed to figure it out. I even added an extra detail to cover if the user enters a negative integer.

```
x = int(raw_input('Enter a positive integer: '))
pwr = 1
root = 0
if (x < 0):
    print 'Sorry, that is not a positive integer.'
else:
    while root**pwr != x:
        pwr = 1
        root = root + 1
        while (root**pwr < x) and (pwr < 5):
            pwr = pwr + 1
    print 'Root = ',root, 'Power = ',pwr
```

The next chapter of my program teachers for-loops. I'm sure this assignment would have went faster had I learned them first.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
p = 1
r = 0
root = 0
pwr = 0
while(r < x):
    while(p < 6):
        if(r ** p == x):
            root = r
            pwr = p
        p = p + 1
    r = r + 1
    p = 0
if (root ** pwr == x):
    print("root =", root, "pwr =", pwr)
else:
    print("There are no such pair")
```

Comment: Please include comments and text explaining what you did. SO is used to help people figure out and solve their problems, not just give them the answer. This way it's more informative and helps people gain value from your response ;)